# Handling Elements and Attributes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Ok so I have gone through many related posts but have not been able to pinpoint an answer to my problem. I need to write an XSLT to transform an XML in the following format

```
<Message>
   <Receiver>
      <name>123</name>
      <address>111</address>
      <phone>1000</phone> 
   </Receiver>
   <List>
      <item>
         <no>1</no>
         <desc>one</desc>
      </item>
      <item>
         <no>2</no>
         <desc>two</desc>
      </item>
   </List>
<Message>
```

to this -

```
<Message>    
   <Receiver name=123>
       <address>111</address>
       <phone>1000</phone> 
   </Receiver>
   <List>
       <item no=1>
          <desc>one</desc>
       </item>
       <item no=2>
          <desc>two</desc>
       </item>
   </List>
</Message>
```

I have tried using the xsl template match tag. 
but has failed miserably. Any ideas or help is much appreciated/

**note i have edited the post to show the actual problem - i initially posted just a part as to avoid confusion but as it seems the problem needs to be stated as a whole. Apologies for inconveniences.

Comment: Downvoters should mention the reason for voting a post down!! It's a courtesy!! I really don't find any foul with this question.. Why this post was voted down??

Comment: If you are satisfied with Tim's answer then  please check a tick mark at the left-top corner of Tim's answer .. that will complete the question and answer process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by building upon the identity template. First you need a template to match the **Receiver** element, copy it but adding the **name** attribute at the same time

```
<xsl:template match="Receiver">
    <Receiver name="{name}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Receiver>
</xsl:template>
```

You can do a similar one for the **item** element. Note how this makes use of "Attribute Value Templates" to create the name attribute from the value of the name element.

Then, you just need a template to match the **name** and **no** elements and ignore them, so they are not output.

```
<xsl:template match="name|no" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Receiver">
        <Receiver name="{name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </Receiver>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <item no="{no}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name|no" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML the following is output

```
<Message>
   <Receiver name="123">
      <address>111</address>
      <phone>1000</phone>
   </Receiver>
   <List>
      <item no="1">
         <desc>one</desc>
      </item>
      <item no="2">
         <desc>two</desc>
      </item>
  </List>
</Message>
```

Now, if you wanted to be more generic, and have a rule where the first 'leaf' element of any parent element is turned into an attribute, then try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[*[1][not(*)]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="{name(*[1])}">
                <xsl:value-of select="*"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*/*[1][not(*)]"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should also output the same results. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader how it works....

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply - as my Original Requirement is to have the <Receiver> node inside another node called <Message>, When I implement the above code inside the <Message> tag this again does not work - is there a specific way to include the above within the <Message> tag ?

Comment: If you can amend your original question to show this, then it sounds straight-forward enough to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again for the explanations as well Tim, rather than just give the code - helped me understand how the whole process works.